# EbeanServer has not been defined ? when running junit test cases

Tags: junit

```
failed: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programatically via registerServer(), took 0.393 sec
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getPrimaryServer(Ebean.java:178)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.access$300(Ebean.java:128)
[error]     at com.avaje.ebean.Ebean.createSqlQuery(Ebean.java:785)
[error]     at models.Amplify.getHierarchy(Amplify.java:42)
[error]     at services.AmplifyNodeServiceImplTest.shouldGetAmplifyNodeInfo(AmplifyNodeServiceImplTest.java:43)
```

when running the JUnit test cases,i am facing the above exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the `play.test.WithServer` class. For example:

```
public class SomeModelTest extends WithServer {
  // Your testing code that uses Ebean
}
```

The `WithServer` class ensures the server is properly initialized (databases, EbeanServer, etc.)